# xcodebuild build action to distribute a dynamic framework with stripped dSYM

Tags: ios, debug-symbols, ios-frameworks, dsym

I used to build our dynamic frameworks for internal development using

```
xcodebuild -workspace <workspace_path> build -configuration "Release"
```

now that we are shipping frameworks to 3rd party developers we want to remove symbols from framework binary.

I noticed that using `build` option the binary always contains the symbols, even if the project is configured with:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym
STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT = YES
STRIP_STYLE = non-global
```

It seems that using `archive` xcodebuild action the framework is generated with a binary without symbols and a separated dSYM file.

However the archive action produce an .xcarchive empty directory (in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<DATE>`)

The generated artifacts (binaries and dSYM) can be found in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project_build_dir>/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/<framework_name>.framework/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos`

- Is it correct to use `archive` to build dynamic frameworks?
- Shouldn't the artifacts be placed in the related .xcarchive?
- Are there other settings that could be used to properly place the generated artifacts in the .xcarchive?
- How do you usually build and distribute a dynamic framework?

----- EDIT: 6/9/2017 -----

> - Are there other settings that could be used to properly place the generated artifacts in the .xcarchive?
> - Shouldn't the artifacts be placed in the related .xcarchive?

After setting this:

```
Skip Install (SKIP_INSTALL) = NO
```

the .xcarchive is properly filled with binary dSYM and other stuff.