# Hide Symbolicated crash logs for a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I've built a dynamic framework which is embedded to one App.
A dynamic framework has a crash function so that the App can trigger a crash.
As the image shown, MyFramework log is symbolicated, while CrashApp's log is not.
How does it work? And how can I build a framework that does not show symbolicated logs?

[image: backtrace]

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053496/xcodebuild-build-action-to-distribute-a-dynamic-framework-with-stripped-dsym)

The issue was because my framework was built under build command instead of archive. Changing to archive strips the symbol from the binary.